# My bitcoin transaction has not cleared in almost a month because I accidentally set the fees too low. What can I do?

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

Transaction ID: 050b5ba38506f8b5fb9054ff2f338999a082236a95f388449e1b8049c72e4f10

Like the title says, I have some bitcoin in a limbo transaction due to ever increasing numbers of unconfirmed transactions with a much higher fee than mine.

My ideal scenario would be to somehow cancel the transaction and have the coins return back to my wallet.

I was told from another source that Bitcoin Core evicts transactions after two weeks by default. However, it seems like that is not the case since it has been over 3 weeks now.

I was also told a method called "child pays for parent" but I am not sure if my situation would work for that.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can spend in another transaction the outputs used in the limbo transaction. Off course, you need to put an higher fee so the new tx will be confirmed and the old will be invalid.